# Upload to sharepoint by code

Tags: perl, sharepoint, upload

I have script that runs and generates an excel sheet. I want to upload that excel sheet to a particular sharepoint URL using perl(preferable) or power shell script. Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Microsoft SharePoint. You can probably use [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent)'s [`post`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#ua-post-url-form-) method:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->post( $url, { 'spreadsheet' => $contents } );
```